# How to filter in queries of wso2 sp complex json processing

Tags: json, wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I have a requirement to execute a complex json processing.
I have almost completed but struck with a logic of filtering the events based on an attribute. I know filtering on a normal basis but this is a case where tokenizeAsObject function is written next to the from statement. 
Where and how he filtering part should be written in this case?
Your help is greatly appreciated.
I could find normal filtering for queries but couldn' find anything having tokenizing method in the querying/analysing data part of the code.

```
--THE CODE GOES HERE
    @App:name('CompanyClientDetailingApp3')
@App:description('Description of the client details of the company')

@source(type='http', receiver.url='http://localhost:5005/clientDetails',
    @map(type='json', @attributes(json = '$')
    )
)
define stream CompanyClientStream3 (json string);

@sink(type = 'log', 
    @map(type = 'passThrough'))
define stream EachProjectStream3 (Client string, clientContractTerm string, projectName string, projectContractTerm int);

@info(name = 'clientProjectquery')
from CompanyClientStream3#json:tokenizeAsObject(json, '$.CompanyClients') 
select json:getString(jsonElement, '$.Client') as Client, json:getString(jsonElement, '$.Invoice.ContractTerm') as clientContractTerm, json:getObject(jsonElement, '$.Invoice.Projects') as projectList 
insert into EachClientProjectStream3;

@info(name = 'projectSttreamQuery')
from EachClientProjectStream3#json:tokenizeAsObject(projectList, "$") 
select Client, clientContractTerm, json:getString(jsonElement, '$.ProjectName') as projectName, json:getInt(jsonElement, '$.ProjectTerm') as projectContractTerm 
insert into EachProjectStream3;
```

Filtering is based on ProjectTerm. i.e. Projects  having Projecterm > 5 years must be streamed out.

```
--Inputs for the same

{
 "CompanyClients": [
   {
     "Client": "C1",
     "Invoice": {
       "ContractTerm": "5",
       "Unit": "years",
       "Projects": [
         {"ProjectName":"C1P1", "ProjectTerm":"5", "TermUnit": "years"},
         {"ProjectName":"C1P2", "ProjectTerm":"3", "TermUnit": "years"},
         {"ProjectName":"C1P3", "ProjectTerm":"2", "TermUnit": "years"}
       ]
     }
   },
   {
     "Client": "C3",
     "Invoice": {
       "ContractTerm": "10",
       "Unit": "years",
       "Projects": [
         {"ProjectName":"C3P1", "ProjectTerm":"8", "TermUnit": "years"},
         {"ProjectName":"C3P2", "ProjectTerm":"5", "TermUnit": "years"},
         {"ProjectName":"C3P3", "ProjectTerm":"6", "TermUnit": "years"}
       ]
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

Thanks,
Kaushik.

Answer (score 0):

Output from the EachProjectStream3 can be filtered in the consecutive query,

```
from EachProjectStream3[projectContractTerm < 5]
slect *
insert into FilteredStream;
```